# No gradients provided for any variable(tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I coded snake game.
I don't know how to pick good parameters, so I picked from my head.
My loss fuction have step(0.0025)
And gradients are None
I don't know why with a normal loss function everything works, but with mine it doesn't (when I add another loss function like MSE to mine, everything works fine).

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input((20,20,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, "tanh"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, "tanh"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, "tanh"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, "tanh"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, "tanh"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, "tanh"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, "tanh")
])

class loss_fn:
    def __init__(self):
        super(loss_fn, self).__init__()
    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):
        global loss
        return tf.convert_to_tensor([loss])

model.compile("adam", loss_fn())

# field size
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 400

# block size
BLOCK_SIZE = 20

# speed
SNAKE_SPEED = 100

# black screen
window = np.zeros((HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# get game field
def get_game_field(snake_segments, food_position, field_size=(20, 20)):
    field = np.zeros((field_size[0], field_size[1], 2), dtype=int)

    for segment in snake_segments:
        x, y = segment
        x = max(min(x//10,19),0)
        y = max(min(y//10,19),0)
        field[y, x, 0] = 1

    x, y = food_position
    x = max(min(x//10,19),0)
    y = max(min(y//10,19),0)
    field[y, x, 1] = 1

    return field

# snake draw function
def draw_snake():
    for segment in snake_segments:
        cv2.rectangle(window, (segment[0], segment[1]), (segment[0] + BLOCK_SIZE, segment[1] + BLOCK_SIZE), (0, 255, 0), -1)

# food draw function
def draw_food():
    cv2.rectangle(window, (food_x, food_y), (food_x + BLOCK_SIZE, food_y + BLOCK_SIZE), (0, 0, 255), -1)

# main loop
while True:
    # init
    snake_x, snake_y = WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2
    snake_dx, snake_dy = 0, 0
    snake_length = 1
    snake_segments = [(snake_x, snake_y)]
    food_x, food_y = random.randint(0, WIDTH // BLOCK_SIZE - 1) * BLOCK_SIZE, random.randint(0, HEIGHT // BLOCK_SIZE - 1) * BLOCK_SIZE
    window.fill(0)

    while True:
        cv2.imshow('Snake Game', window)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1000 // SNAKE_SPEED)
        action = model(get_game_field(snake_segments, (food_x, food_y)).reshape((1,20,20,2)))[0].numpy()
        loss = 1-(snake_length-1)/(WIDTH*HEIGHT/(BLOCK_SIZE**2))
        # do action
        if action[0] > 0 and snake_dy == 0:
            snake_dx, snake_dy = 0, -BLOCK_SIZE
        elif action[0] < 0 and snake_dy == 0:
            snake_dx, snake_dy = 0, BLOCK_SIZE
        elif action[1] > 0 and snake_dx == 0:
            snake_dx, snake_dy = -BLOCK_SIZE, 0
        elif action[1] < 0 and snake_dx == 0:
            snake_dx, snake_dy = BLOCK_SIZE, 0

        snake_x += snake_dx
        snake_y += snake_dy

        if snake_x < 0 or snake_x >= WIDTH or snake_y < 0 or snake_y >= HEIGHT:
            break

        if snake_x == food_x and snake_y == food_y:
            snake_length += 1
            food_x, food_y = random.randint(0, WIDTH // BLOCK_SIZE - 1) * BLOCK_SIZE, random.randint(0, HEIGHT // BLOCK_SIZE - 1) * BLOCK_SIZE

        snake_segments.append((snake_x, snake_y))

        if len(snake_segments) > snake_length:
            del snake_segments[0]

        window.fill(0)
        draw_snake()
        draw_food()

        # print action
        print(action)

        # print loss
        print(loss)

        # train
        model.fit(get_game_field(snake_segments, (food_x, food_y)).reshape((1,20,20,2)), np.array([loss]), 1)

        if ((snake_x, snake_y) in snake_segments[:-1]) or (key == ord("r")):
            break
        if key in [27, ord("q")]:
            quit()
```

and this code returns
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0', 'dense_4/kernel:0', 'dense_4/bias:0', 'dense_5/kernel:0', 'dense_5/bias:0', 'dense_6/kernel:0', 'dense_6/bias:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(800, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(512, 512) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(512, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_2/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_3/kernel:0' shape=(256, 256) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_3/bias:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_4/kernel:0' shape=(256, 16) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_4/bias:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_5/kernel:0' shape=(16, 16) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_5/bias:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_6/kernel:0' shape=(16, 2) dtype=float32>), (None, <tf.Variable 'dense_6/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32>)).

i tried use GradientTape but i get same message but with model variables

Comment: your `custom loss function` does not provide `gradients` for the variables in your model. To fix this issue, you can use the `tf.GradientTape` context manager to compute the gradients explicitly.